# How to enforce all UPPERCASE letter for static variables in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to enforce (using a hint in the editor) capital letters for static variables (constants!).

If I write `private static final float decayFactor = 0.5f;` it *should* hint that static variables should be capital letters.

Tried looking in the Preferences->code style, but didn't find something like that. Inspections don't seem to have something relevant either, as you can see from the **screenshot**:

[image: code generation screen shot]

Comment: My first thought was: "bah, intellij does that". But just checked: no, it doesn't. But a hint: you shouldnt hint for *static* variables per se: it is about **constants** that should use uppercase. And just because something is final static doesn't mean it is really a constant. It could, but isn't necessarily.

Comment: I would say this is something for [Checkstyle](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea). Specifically the [ConstantName check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#ConstantName).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intellij does that ;-)

Go to Inspections > Java > Naming conventions > Field naming convention.

Check this inspection, and check "'static' field" into the options of the inspection. You'll be able to define the regex used to validate the naming of the static variables. By default, it is [A-Z][A-Z_\d]*, which is what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not auto-suggest the correct refactor/renaming pattern. :-(